# html div within div

Tags: html, css

The div is nested in another div, has its margins and padding at 0, at its width and height set at > 0. Why is the display: inline turning its width and height to 0?

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>

 .c
 {
   width: 300px;
  height:  50px;
  margin:0px;
   padding:0px;

 }


 #a
 {
    display:inline;padding:0px; margin:0px;width:100px;height:20px;

 }

</style>
</head>
 <body>


    <div class="c">
       <div id="a" style="background-color:#ff0000;"></div>
   </div>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply because inline elements don't have a width and height.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it to be inline, set it as an inline-block, like so:

```
#a {

   display:inline-block;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because inline no long displays the div as a block, which is what you want.

W3CSchools defines `display:inline;`

> The element is displayed as an inline element (like span). An inline element has no line break before or after it, and it tolerates HTML elements next to it

In order for your div to appear you have to keep it as `display:block;` (default). If you're trying to get text next to it, you should try `float:left;`

Comment: And there's always `display: inline-block`

Comment: That is also true but `display:inline-block` often has trouble in older versions of IE for an element that by default is block - but it is also a possible solution.